# Does the "timeline" parameter work correctly?

Tags: support

I wanted to see if there was a serial downvoter yesterday so I looked at: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6521245/timeline

I did not see any downvotes at all although there are several

Am I misunderstanding what the /timeline does?

Comment: You mean that 1 dv on your answer there?

Comment: Yes and in the accepted one which I cannot see when was either

Comment: Well 1 dv is not serial down voting for sure. And second if you want to see the timeline of your answer there, you need to use the id of your answer and not of the question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6521571/timeline (Also voting is anonymous, you only see when someone voted)

Comment: Ahh - I was under the impression I would see all activity - so you answered my question :)

Comment: If you click on the share button of any post you see the ID of the post, which you then can use for the `post/ID/timeline` url. (Not the last number, the last number is your user ID :)

Comment: That does not seem to work the way I thought. What would be the urls for the accepted answer and my answer?

Comment: [Accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6521513/timeline), [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6521571/timeline). But seriously, going around posting comments about downvotes is a waste of time. If you see nothing wrong with your answer, ignore the downvote and get on with your life.

Comment: Thanks - if I can get just ONE down voter to add a comment when voting, I'll be happier :)

Comment: Nitpicking, but technically it is frowned upon to comment on your votes, voting is anonymous for a reason. By all means, comment on any improvements you think can be made in a post, but don't comment on your votes.

Comment: Frowned upon by whom? I totally disagree. I have been active at SO for more than 5 years and detest being voted down without being told why. If I am wrong I want to hear why and have a chance to defend my code in case the down voter misunderstood or was unable to implement my answer and got frustrated. Perhaps I could clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the [/timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6521245/timeline) feature works as designed. It shows the public events for a given post id. It is relevant to know that both questions and answers have their own post id. The post id for an answer can be found on the share link of the answer or is reachable from the question timeline:

[image: timeline has links to the answer timeline]

If you find yourself often visiting the timeline. you might consider adding an user script that add the link to each post. An example of such script is [this one](https://github.com/Tunaki/stackoverflow-userscripts/blob/master/showtimeline.user.js) from user [Tunaki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1743880/tunaki) but Stack Apps has more options, like [this one](https://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-a)